# Segmantation Fault in Python when append arrays

Tags: python, linux, word2vec

I'm trying append arrays in python (in linux) like this:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
data = []
for file_name in file_list:
   with open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
      data = data.append(word_tokenize(file.read()))
```

My file_list has 20k files, with ~5k of words each, and any moment, python process is aborted and show this message:

```
Segmantation Fault
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Also, please cut and paste the entire error message, including trace-back.  It would also help to include a tracing `print` so we know which loop iteration caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If that's the full code to trigger, it's likely a memory issue.

What's the OS, Python-version (including whether 32-bit or 64-bit), and available RAM in the machine? How many files does it get through before the error, and does it always error the exact (or similar) time?